# $emit is not working when trying to emit a custom class Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

So I am trying to close a modal my markup looks like thi s

```
<modal v-show="isVisible"></modal>
<button @click="isVisible=true" @close="isVisible=false">Show Modal</button>
```

My componenet is like this

```
Vue.component('modal',{

    template:`<div id="exampleModalPopovers" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalPopoversLabel" style="display: block; padding-right: 15px;">
                  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalPopoversLabel">Modal title</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                        </button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <h5>Popover in a modal</h5>
                        <p>This <a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-secondary popover-test" title="" data-content="Popover body content is set in this attribute." data-original-title="Popover title">button</a> triggers a popover on click.</p>
                        <hr>
                        <h5>Tooltips in a modal</h5>
                        <p><a href="#" class="tooltip-test" title="" data-original-title="Tooltip">This link</a> and <a href="#" class="tooltip-test" title="" data-original-title="Tooltip">that link</a> have tooltips on hover.</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" @click="$emit('close')">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>`
})

new Vue({

    el: '#root',
    data:{
           isVisible:false
         }
})
```

So the Modal opens fine but when I try to click on the close button of the modal its not working and I don't find any error also

Comment: what is `@close`, Can you provided docs around it?

Comment: @Saurabh its a custom class it comes under Vue2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put `@close` on the modal:

```
<modal v-show="isVisible" @close="isVisible=false"></modal>
```

Because the event is emitted from the modal, not the button.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html), than you have to modify it like this:

```
<modal @close="isVisible=false" v-show="isVisible"></modal>
<button @click="isVisible=true">Show Modal</button>
```

You are emitting the close event here, inside modal component:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" @click="$emit('close')">Close</button>
```

so it will be receiving that event at `modal`.